# Wordpress perform a search on widget text

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know of a hack or search plugin that will scan the Widgets Text (Arbitrary text). Currently I'm noticing that only text in the Pages text area is being consider in the search. But I have Text widgets with just as important text on it not being consider in the search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems:

1. The widget text is saved as an serialized array in the options table. Go to `/wp-admin/options.php` to see it. Searching here is difficult and probably very slow.
2. A widget has no URI. What should be the link’s target in a search result?
3. Some widgets contain text which is available elsewhere (latest posts etc.). Which position should be preferred?

You *can* search in widget options and create nice URIs for widgets using the rewrite API – but 3. is rather difficult. I couldn’t come up with an elegant solution for this.

FYI: There’s a whole network of WordPress hackers on [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). You may have more luck there.